# Determine all natural numbers which when divided by 17 leave the remainder 3 and when divided by 6 leave the remainder 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

> Determine all natural numbers which
>
> - when divided by 17 leave the remainder 3
> - when divided by 6 leave the remainder 1.

Do I have to use Diophantine equations? Could you please help me with this? I don't even know where I should start.

I appreciate all help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two Diophantine equations in $3$ unknowns

$$n = 17 q_1 + 3 \qquad  \qquad \qquad n = 6 q_2 + 1$$

Doing (integer) Gaussian elimination,

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -17 & 0 & 3\\ 1 & 0 & -6 & 1\end{array}\right]$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & -17 & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 17 & -6 & -2\end{array}\right]$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & -6 & 1\\ 0 & 17 & -6 & -2\end{array}\right]$$

The solution set in $\mathbb R^3$ is a line parametrized as follows

$$n = 6 m + 1 \qquad  \qquad \qquad 17 q_1 = 6 m - 2 \qquad  \qquad \qquad q_2 = m$$

However, we are interested in integer solutions only. Hence, $6 m - 2$ must be divisible by $17$. Note that if $m = 6$, then $6 m - 2 = 36 - 2 = 34 = 2 \cdot 17$. If $m = 6 + 17 k$, where $k \in \mathbb N$, then

$$6 m - 2 = 6 (6 + 17 k) - 2 = 17 \cdot (2 + 6 k) = 34 + 102 k$$

Thus, the values of $n$ that satisfy the constraints are given by

$$n \in \color{blue}{\{ 37 + 102 k \mid k \in \mathbb N\}}$$

Comment: Verifying in **Haskell**: `take 10 $ filter (\n->rem n 17==3 && rem n 6==1) [ n | n <- [0,1..] ]` produces the list `[37,139,241,343,445,547,649,751,853,955]`.

Answer (score 7):

17 and 6 are relatively prime, so by the Chinese remainder theorem there is a unique solution $N$ modulo $17×6=102$:
$$\begin{align}N&\equiv3\bmod17\\
N&\equiv1\bmod6\end{align}$$
Since we only have two congruences to deal with, just guessing a solution is viable, and we see that $N=37$ works. The natural numbers that satisfy the two conditions are therefore
$$N=37+102k,\ k\in\Bbb N_0$$

Comment: thanks for ur answer. How would I end up with the "N=37" result in case of more than 3 congruences?

Comment: @GeidhslioFidiokerk See the Wikipedia page on the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). It contains more than you ask for, including an explicit construction of N.